# getElemetById always return first object, how i can get other values?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
     var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('detail');
     ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
     }
  }
  var prezime = document.getElementById('form1').getAttribute('value');
  var queryString = "?prezime=" + prezime ;
```

**PHP**

```
echo '<input type="text" id="form1" class="button1" value="'. $row["prezime"] .'" 
name="'. $row["prezime"] .'" onclick="ajaxFunctionII()" >';
echo("</form>");
```

Comment: An ID should always be unique, thus there should be no more than one element with that specific id.

Comment: If you find yourself using more than one instance of a particular id attribute on your page, you should consider using a class attribute instead - IDs should be unique.

Comment: if i get id value in php how i call that back in html?

Comment: @user1024610 How do you mean, "call that back in HTML"?

Answer (score 2):

`Id` is always `unique` to `one element`, you should not use same id for more than one element.
even though you use, the getElementById will select only the 1st element the DOM find, it wont look for any other element.

Make use of `name` or `class` and to get these elements use `getElementsByName` and `getElementsByClassName`.

**[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)**

Comment: Note that getElementByClass isn't supported by IE, I believe.

Comment: If any, it should be `getElementsByClassName` and yes, it is not supported by IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

More than one element with same ID is bad, invalid and will cause problems. Don't do that.

Give each element different ID and if you want to have them in "groups" give them a `name`.

To get collection of elements by name have this:

```
var arrButtons = document.getElementsByName("detail");
ajaxDisplay = arrButtons[1];
ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

In the above, you will assign the second button.

Comment: ok, if i in php file bive id value from mysql, how i can get that value in html echo '<input type="button" **id="'. $row["prezime"] .'"** class="button1" value="'. $row["prezime"] .'" name="'. $row["prezime"] .'" onclick="ajaxFunctionII()" >';

Comment: Don't know, sorry, and can't see how it's relevant to your question or my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we should be having only one element within a DOM, with any given id value.

You can try `document.getElementsByTagName` and `document.getElementsByName`.

If you are using jQuery, it should be very simple `$('#id') or $('.classname')` will return all matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

you should go with class instead of id.the same issue is solved on the given link please check that.

[Get multiple elements by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338716/get-multiple-elements-by-id)

Comment: i getting name from mysql search in php, which is call back with ajax to html, how i can call that in html if i don't know name?

Comment: so did you use jquery? if yes then it is easy.
you can use $('#idname').each(function(){$(this).val();})