# Adding select/deselect all to dynamic tabular form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which contains buttons to add and delete rows. My javascript function to check all checkboxes works for the first row, but once I add more rows to the form, the first row is still the only one that gets checked.

Any tips?

Here is my javascript function:

```
<code>
//checks all rows
function checkAll() {
var masterCheck = document.getElementById('masterCheck');
var on = false;
if(masterCheck.checked==true) {
    document.getElementById('checkbox').checked=true;
} else {
    document.getElementById('checkbox').checked=false;
}
}
</code>
```

And here is the form:
http://crimsonroot.com/files/freelance/new.html

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get multiple elements by Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338716/get-multiple-elements-by-id)

Comment: The getElementById() method only accesses the first element with the specified id. You shouldnt be giving elements the same id's.

Comment: getElementById() will only ever return one element. You'll have to search by element class or type, and then loop through all the results. (Or use jquery to simplify this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong! @Mohammed your answer really helped. There were just one or two syntax errors that I found. In order to check and uncheck all of the boxes, I needed to add a boolean variable as an input to the function as follows:

```
//checks all rows
function checkAll(bool) {
    var masterCheck = document.getElementById('masterCheck');
    var allcheck = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var on = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < allcheck.length; i++) {
        if (masterCheck.checked == true) {
            allcheck[i].checked = true;
        } else {
            allcheck[i].checked = false;
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason, this was the final piece to the puzzle. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this.

```
$("#masterCheck").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

Comment: This looks great. I'm having trouble getting it to work though. If I have the jQuery for Bootstrap on the form already do I need to add anything else to the document to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since `document.getElementById()` returns first element, because id cannot be used more than one. To make it usable, add a class checkbox and try the following code:

```
//checks all rows
function checkAll() {
    var masterCheck = document.getElementById('masterCheck');
    var allcheck = getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var on = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < allcheck.length; i++) {
        if (masterCheck.checked == true) {
            allchecked[i].checked = true;
        } else {
            allchecked[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome! For some reason it's not working...I changed the id to class="checkbox". Does it have something to do with the fact that the rows don't exist until the add row button is clicked?