# Is loop a good choice instead of what I have created?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am learning JS by my own and I have created first little script :). Script is counting the number of signs for the tag tittle of a webpage to be between 50 and 60 etc.... Below there is one button that resets all the data in the script and its working 100% but I have a question -  Can I use some kind of loop instead of that code that I have created? A loop that will be reseting all elements below. Thx for Your help :) and advice...

```
// reset Title tag check
document.getElementById("resetTitleBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById('inputTitleTag').value = "";
  document.getElementById('titleTag').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("tytul").style.color = "";
  document.getElementById("good").innerHTML = "";
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338716/get-multiple-elements-by-id)

Comment: if all element needs reset with `innerHTML` loop is fine. But here you have other properties to be cleared. then it's better to continue with this rather than a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think in this case a loop is necassary, you could do something like this:

```
// reset Title tag check
document.getElementById("resetTitleBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var tags = ['titleTag', 'example', 'good'];
  for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(tag).value = "";
  }
  document.getElementById('inputTitleTag').value = "";
  document.getElementById("tytul").style.color = "";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done with a loops:

```js
var resets = [
  {id: 'inputTitleTag', props: ['value']},
  {id: 'titleTag', props: ['value']},
  {id: 'example', props: ['innerHTML']},
  {id: 'tytul', props: ['style', 'color']},
  {id: 'good', props: ['innerHTML']}
]
document.getElementById("resetTitleBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  resets.forEach(function(reset) {
    reset.props.length === 1 ? document.getElementById(reset.id)[reset.props[0]] = "" : document.getElementById(reset.id)[reset.props[0]][reset.props[1]] = "";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group these `ids` in an array and loop over the array for applying similar operation.

Since `inputTitleTag` and  `tytul` do not share operation with others, there is no point in looping over them.

```
document.getElementById("resetTitleBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var ids = ['titleTag', 'example', 'good'];
  document.getElementById('inputTitleTag').value = "";
  document.getElementById("tytul").style.color = "";
  ids.forEach(function(id){
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are concerned about is being more dry.  Or `do not repeat yourself` then you could alias a few of your more commonly used functions.  Then looping mechanisms are also nice when a pattern is noticed such as all three of the same prop.  Usually two or less of the same prop is pointless for a loop as a minimum loop is usually 2-3 lines to declare.

```
const clear = (element, prop) => element[prop] = "";
const get = (id) => document.getElementById(id);

get("resetTitleBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  ['titleTag', 'example', 'good'].forEach(id => clear(get(id), 'innerHTML'));
  clear(get('inputTitleTag'), 'value'));
  clear(get('tytul').style, 'color'));
});
```

This doesn't necessarily improve this sample segment of code but can lead to a more dry pattern throughout the project for commonly used functions.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using classes to identify different elements requiring common initialization and select them that way.

```
var resetValueEls     = document.getElementsByClassName('initValue');
var resetInnerHTMLEls = document.getElementsByClassName('initInnerHTML');
var resetColorEls     = document.getElementsByClassName('initColor');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(resetValueEls,     function(x) {x.value     = ""})
Array.prototype.forEach.call(resetInnerHTMLEls, function(x) {x.innerHTML = ""})
Array.prototype.forEach.call(resetColorEls,     function(x) {x.style.color = ""})
```

then, each HTML tag that requires initialization gets a class or combination thereof e.g. `<DIV class="initInnerHTML initColor"/>`.

The benefit of this strategy is that if you have many tags to initialize, despite having many ids, you have a small number of classes to keep track of in your initializer.

Comment: This could also be combined with @Faly's solution to write the above in a more compact way.  One line with an object relating class names to property/operations, and a loop over those containing a single `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.