# How to combine getElementById with different Id name

Tags: javascript

It is possible to combine getElementById with different id name? How to achieve it?

```js
function onOpen(){
    var x1 = document.getElementById("header");
    var x2 = document.getElementById("menu");
    var x3 = document.getElementById("program");
    x1.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
    x2.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
    x3.style.filter = "blur(5px)"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ?  Give an example. The question is too broad to awnser for now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338716/get-multiple-elements-by-id

Comment: @IonutEugen he wants to not have to set each elements blur line by line, he wants to be able to do it all at once, or in a smaller code base. instead of Line by Line like shown. That's my take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` and than iterate using `NodeList.forEach()`

```js
function onOpen(){
  const els = document.querySelectorAll("#header, #menu, #program");
  els.forEach(el => el.style.filter = "blur(5px)");
}

onOpen();
```

```html
<div id="header">TEST</div>
<div id="menu">TEST</div>
<div id="program">TEST</div>
```

Or if you want to *pollute* HTML with an extra class, you could use

```js
function onOpen(){
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(".onOpenBlur");
  els.forEach(el => el.style.filter = "blur(5px)");
}

onOpen();
```

```html
<div class="onOpenBlur" id="header">TEST</div>
<div class="onOpenBlur" id="menu">TEST</div>
<div class="onOpenBlur" id="program">TEST</div>
```

that way, in the future, all you have to do is add the same class to any number of elements, instead of nesting a new ID into JS...
Pick the one that best fits. Or you can even use both: `'#header, #menu, .onOpenBlur'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

### A slightly different approach

Another idea would be to just add a class to `body` and let CSS do the magic:

```js
function toggleOpen(){
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('is-open')
}

toggleOpen();
```

```css
.is-open .on-open-blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="on-open-blur" id="header">TEST</div>
<div class="on-open-blur" id="menu">TEST</div>
<div class="on-open-blur" id="program">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Oh I forgot about that. My bad, I suggest some more documentation on HTML dom.

Comment: TQ for that, I about to rename all my class name then you came in. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Id's are unique so as far as I know you can't select more than one at a time. You can however select multiple classes with document.getElementsByClass and have one class specified for all of them.

Comment: i see. I understood now. TQ