# I have to use my script with document.getElementById("") multiple times

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I'm making a layout where each box has to use a... id="top1", id="top2", id="top3", etc... so that when you click it goes to the top of the document, but I can't find a way to make that happen, whow can I use only one function to do this without repeat it multiple times? I would be very grateful to hear a solution, thanks in advance

I Try to do something like this so that clicking on each box makes the document scroll to the top:

```
const top1 = document.getElementById("top1, top 2, top3")
   top1.addEventListener('click', () => {
         window.scrollTo(0, 0)
       })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get multiple elements by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338716/get-multiple-elements-by-id)

Comment: You can't pass multiple ids separated by commas. Instead, you should call ```getElementById``` for each id and add an event listener to each returned element.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElememtById()` can only search for a single ID at a time.

Don't use different IDs. Give them all `class="top"`, then you can get them all with `document.querySelectorAll(".top")`, and loop over this result.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".top").forEach(top => top1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}));
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works, I didn't know how to use document.querySelectorAll thank you very much

Comment: Did you know how to use `document.getElementsByClassName()`? You could also use that.