# How to select the last one of a certain element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selector, getelementbyid

I have several `<select>` elements in my page. Is there any easy way to select the last one of them? This brings me the first one:

```
document.getElementById("myList")
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for the wrong usage of `getElementById`. Let me change my question: How to access the last one of a certain element using `getElementsByTagName`?

`document.getElementsByTagName("select")`

Comment: There should only be one element with the id `mylist`...

Comment: The id of an element has to be unique, you must not have more then one element with the id `myList`. Use e.g. _class_  instead [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName would be better for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Comment: Sorry for wrong usage of getElementById. Let me change my question: How to access the last one of a certain element using getElementsByTagName? Ex. document.getElementsByTagName("select")

Comment: [Marcus Abrahão](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33696531/1960455) already answered how to get the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using more than one element with the same Id. A better option is `document.getElementsByTagName` i. e. `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[document.getElementsByTagName("input").length - 1]`

Answer (score 12):

```
var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var lastSelect = allSelects[allSelects.length-1];
```

Answer (score 5):

A more elegant solution:

```
document.querySelector("select:last-child")
```