# Hide Multiple Elements in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to show/hide multiple ID of elements.

I have a problem with the javascript in my HTML file.

Here's the javascript:

```
<Script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
function HideContent(d){
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d){
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
//--></script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class = "left" id="colsxmenu">
<ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:HideContent('colsxmenu')"> ENGLISH</a>
       <li><a href="javascript:HideContent('uniquename')">FRENCH</a>
```

Actually, if I select ENGLISH it works good hiding the `colsxmenu`, but what I need is if I select FRENCH it should hide more than only 1 elements.

I tried to add `('colsxmenu';'colsxmenu2')`, but that didn't works.

Comment: First multiple arguments are separated with a comma. Second, your function is only coded to handle one element.

Comment: I think [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id) you will find the answer

Comment: You can't use same ID for multiple elements. It's ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of elements to your function

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
<a href="javascript:HideContent(['first','second'])"> ENGLISH</a>
<script>
  function HideContent(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById([obj[i]]).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your HideContent function to accept variable number of argument. It should be some thing like below to hide multiple elements.

```
<script>
  function HideContent() {
    if (arguments.length > 0){
      for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++{
        document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
</script>
```

After that you can call it like

```
HideContent('colsxmenu');
HideContent('colsxmenu', 'uniqename');
```