# Get div value by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript, I am trying to get the value of div on click in JavaScript.
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableCell" >DEPARTURE TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ARRIVAL TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">BUS TYPE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">AVAILABLE SEATS</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">STATUS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey();">
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="departure_time">1200</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="arrival_time">1615</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey();">
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="departure_time">8888</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="arrival_time">9999</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
        color: #fff;
        display: table-header-group;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        width:30%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function hey() {
  alert("sdsdsd");
  var departure = document.getElementById("departure_time").innerHTML;
  alert(departure);
  var arrival = document.getElementById("arrival_time").innerHTML;
  alert(arrival);
}
```

Basically, its a table created in DIV tags, and the data shown here is from web service response.
When I click on any **divTableRow** it only gives me the result of first row, But what I want is if user click on second row it should alert the second row data.

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cgxyj45b/11/) to JSFiddle

Comment: Don't use the same ID for multiple elements, use class insted

Comment: The problem is because you have multiple elements with the same `id`. This is invalid HTML.

Comment: Basically divTableRow  filled by web service response, so I cant change the id for every row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Comment: @BilalZafar  :- `Basically divTableRow filled by web service response,` ok, but html is created by you? Isn't it? If yes then you can change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the same ID multiple times, change thm to classes. Thereafter if you want to do this with vanilla javascript use pass a reference to the row in your method call `hey` and use `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
window.hey = function(div){
  var departure = div.getElementsByClassName("departure_time")[0].innerHTML;
  alert(departure);
  var arrival = div.getElementsByClassName("arrival_time")[0].innerHTML;
  alert(arrival);  
};
```

```css
.divTable{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-header-group;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  width:30%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
   <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell" >DEPARTURE TIME</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">ARRIVAL TIME</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">BUS TYPE</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">AVAILABLE SEATS</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">STATUS</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey(this);">
      <div class="divTableCell1 departure_time">1200</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1 arrival_time">1615</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey(this)">
      <div class="divTableCell1 departure_time">8888</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1 arrival_time">9999</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have multiple elements with same ID on a page. Change *departure_time* and *arrival_time* to classes.

Then you may add a parameter to your event, like this:

```
<div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey(this);">
```

The *this* keyword is an HTML element that triggered this event.
In your javascript you can use it this way:

```
function hey(element) {
    var departure = element.getElementsByClassName("departure_time")[0].innerText;
    var arrival = element.getElementsByClassName("arrival_time")[0].innerText;
    alert(departure);
    alert(arrival);
}
```

---

And the whole snippet might look like this:

```js
function hey(element) {
    var departure = element.getElementsByClassName("departure_time")[0].innerText;
    var arrival = element.getElementsByClassName("arrival_time")[0].innerText;
    alert(departure);
    alert(arrival);
}
```

```css
.divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
        color: #fff;
        display: table-header-group;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        width:30%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableCell" >DEPARTURE TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ARRIVAL TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">BUS TYPE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">AVAILABLE SEATS</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">STATUS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey(this);">
      <div class="divTableCell1 departure_time">1200</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1 arrival_time">1615</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow" onclick="hey(this);">
      <div class="divTableCell1 departure_time">8888</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1 arrival_time">9999</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's such a thing as `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Yes there is, but we only want to get elements that are children of clicked element.

Comment: But you have the clicked element in your method. `element.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

As you added tag jQuery, you can use the following snippet to solve your issue:

```
$("div.divTableRow").click(function(){
  var departure = $(this).find("#departure_time").text();
  alert(departure);
  var arrival = $(this).find("#arrival_time").text(); 
  alert(arrival);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cgxyj45b/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuerys click handler, so you can reference the clicked element within the click handler. The idea is to limit the scope ("#departure_time WITHIN the clicked row"). The answer, of course, is only valid as long as "filled by web service response" is true. Normally, you would use classes for

https://api.jquery.com/click/

```js
$('.divTableRow').click(hey);

function hey (evt) {
  alert("sdsdsd");
  var departure = $(this).find('#departure_time').text();
  alert(departure);
  var arrival = $(this).find('#arrival_time').text();
  alert(arrival);
}
```

```css
.divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
        text-align: -webkit-center;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: rgba(0, 102, 179, 0.6) !important;
        color: #fff;
        display: table-header-group;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        width:30%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableCell1, .divTableHead {
        border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .divTableHeading {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
      <div class="divTableRow">
          <div class="divTableCell" >DEPARTURE TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ARRIVAL TIME</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">FARE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">BUS TYPE</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">AVAILABLE SEATS</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">STATUS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody" id="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="departure_time">1200</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="arrival_time">1615</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="departure_time">8888</div> 
      <div class="divTableCell1" id="arrival_time">9999</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">1600</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">VOLVO</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">8</div>
      <div class="divTableCell1">OK</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You still shouldnt have multiple ID's. You could easily craft a jQuery solution which uses class names.

Comment: @Jamiec That's why I quoted the OPs sentence about getting the data from a web service with that bogus multiple IDs.