# How to use javascript function for more than one tag with similar id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript to change the color of the text of a tag by mouseover function on other tag written in html.
ex:

```js
function mouseoverbox1() {
  var mypara = document.getElementById("a1");
  mypara.style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="mouseoverbox1()">
  <a id="a1">Color</a>
  <a id="a1">Names</a>
  <a id="a1">Places</a>
</div>
```

Now as I run the code only the color of tag "Color" changes to green  and not of Names and Places. Is there any way that my function could accept the changes to all anchor tags with similar id???

Comment: id need to be unique,

Comment: You cannot have multiple a tags with same IDs. You need to use classes for that.

Comment: You can't have same id for several tags in your HTML DOM. Furthermore, if you want to keep this *ugly* DOM, use `getElementsByAttribute( "id", "a1")` instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Comment: You should use CSS for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `mouseoverbox1()` on each `a` instead of the parent `div` with parameter `this`. Then inside the function first reset the `color` property of all `a`. Finally set `color` only to the currently passed `a`.

**Please Note:** The `id` should be unique in a document. You can use `class` instead.

Try the following way:

```js
function mouseoverbox1(that){
  document.querySelectorAll("#tagContainer > a.a1").forEach(function(el){
    el.style.color = "";
  });
  that.style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tagContainer">
    <a class="a1" onmouseover="mouseoverbox1(this)">Color</a>
    <a class="a1" onmouseover="mouseoverbox1(this)">Names</a>
    <a class="a1" onmouseover="mouseoverbox1(this)">Places</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bad solutions in many ways. It fails to address the duplicate ID problem, and it would target **all** anchor tags on the whole page.

Comment: @connexo, I have updated my answer. Please have look. Thanks for helping me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use classes instead.

In Javascript you can then get an array of all elements with the same class.

```js
function handleBoxMouseover () {
  // Get all child elements with the class "a1" and save them into an array
  var childElements = document.getElementsByClassName('a1');

  // iterate through the new array and change the color by the array index
  for (var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
    childElements[i].style.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="handleBoxMouseover()">
  <a class="a1">Color</a>
  <a class="a1">Names</a>
  <a class="a1">Places</a>
</div>
```

Just FYI:

Instead of changing the inline-styles you could also add a class to the childElements to change the color.

Comment: i`m just adding an answer like that :D

Comment: this will color all the text at once

Comment: @brk that's right. I wanted to keep it the same approach as the op. Your solution would work for just separated onmouseover checks.

Answer (score 3):

`id` need to be unique.The same objective can be met using `document.querySelectorAll` and a class, since multiple elements can have same `class`

```js
//get all the elements with same class name
// iterate it using array#forEach menthod
document.querySelectorAll('.a1').forEach(function(item) {
  // add event to each of the element
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    this.style.color = "green";
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="a1">Color</a>
  <a class="a1">Names</a>
  <a class="a1">Places</a>
</div>
```

Note: This will color individual text on mouseover, but if the requirement is to color all the text at once , then add the eventhandler to the parent element

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that my function could accept the changes to all
>   anchor tags with similar id???

**`Id`s must be unique, or you will get into issues like this.**

That said, you shouldn't be using `getElementById` if you want to keep the `id` same, use **`querySelectorAll`** instead

```
function mouseoverbox1(){
    document.querySelectorAll("[id='a1']").forEach( function( ele ){
       ele.style.color = "green";
    });
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function mouseoverbox1(){
    document.querySelectorAll("[id='a1']").forEach( function( ele ){
       ele.style.color = "green";
    });
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="mouseoverbox1()">
    <a id="a1">Color</a>
    <a id="a1">Names</a>
    <a id="a1">Places</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have many JS solutions I will post the missing simplest (and probably most appropriate) solution for this problem: CSS.

```css
div a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="a1">Color</a>
  <a id="a1">Names</a>
  <a id="a1">Places</a>
</div>
```