# DOM query in JavaScript which can locate some element whose previous sibling value is as given value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have below code snippet.

```html
    <caption>TEST Value</caption>
    <table *ngIf="settings" class="table" id="datatable">

    <caption>TEST Value1</caption>
    <table *ngIf="settings" class="table" id="datatable">
    <caption>TEST Value</caption>
    <table *ngIf="settings" class="table" id="datatable">
    <caption>TEST Value2</caption>
    <table *ngIf="settings" class="table" id="datatable">
    <caption>TEST Value3</caption>
    <table *ngIf="settings" class="table" id="datatable">
```

Now  I want to locate HTML element (which is table) whose just previous sibling value is as given.
For example: I want to locate HTML element whose caption is TEST Value3, in that case it should return reference of that particular table.
Notice

```
document.getElementById('datatable').previousElementSibling.innerHTML
```

gives me very first table by id and its sibling TEST Value. All tables have same ID, so `document.getElementByID()` will return very first table also and that's why I want to take advantage of caption to identify individual table. You can  always ignore duplicate IDs and can use any selector like by tagname, etc.

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid HTML, fix that first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Comment: If the Html keeps the pattern of caption followed by table then just query both and use indexing to find table under the index for the caption you want.