# How to show the selected element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to open a modal that shows a pdf according to the selected text, but only the first one in the list is shown. What should I do?

index.html

```
<p><a id="other-activies-link">Semana Omnistack 11</a></p>
<p><a id="other-activies-link">28ª Semana do IME</a></p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <iframe id="myFrame" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

scripts.js

```
const selectedActivity = document.querySelectorAll("#other-activies-link");

selectedActivity.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById(
      "myFrame"
    ).src = `/files/${event.target.textContent}.pdf`;
  });
});
```

Comment: id should be unique. try with same class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't use same `id` element, it would work here but it's frowned upon. I've created a demo with the same `class`. Of course, the `iframe` wouldn't load. I've done the explaining in the code itself. See, if it works for you.

```js
const selectedActivity = document.querySelectorAll(".other-activies-link");

selectedActivity.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (event) => { // pass event parameter here
  
    document.getElementById(
      "myFrame"
    ).src = `/files/${event.target.innerText}.pdf`; // use innerText instead
    console.clear();
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<p><a class="other-activies-link">Semana<br> Omnistack 11</a></p>
<p><a class="other-activies-link">28ª Semana do IME</a></p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <iframe id="myFrame" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

See the difference between `innerText` and `textContent` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Comment: I replaced the ids with classes and the textcontent with innnertext and the modals didn't open anymore

Comment: But replacing just the ids with classes worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use non-unique ids. If you replace id with a class, the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes instead, id's of elements should always be unique

```html
<p><a class="other-activies-link">Semana Omnistack 11</a></p>
<p><a class="other-activies-link">28ª Semana do IME</a></p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <iframe id="myFrame" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

This should work,

```js
const selectedActivity = document.querySelectorAll(".other-activies-link");

...
```