# Change input color to green with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, forms, input

I have this quizz form:

```html
<section>
    <form name="formulaire" >
        <h3>1. Le rôle du HTML est de : </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="a">  a. Mettre en forme du texte <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="b" id="correct">  b. Structurer un document <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="c">  c. Lier un document à une feuille de style <br/>

        <h3>2. Pour définir un titre dans une page HTML, on utilise : </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="a" id="correct">  a. La balise title <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="b">  b. La balise titre <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="c">  c. La balise head <br/>

        <h3>3. A quoi sert l'attribut alt de la balise img ? </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="a">  a. A afficher une deuxième image si la première ne peut pas s'afficher <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="b">  b. A donner un lien alternatif vers l'image si le premier est cassé <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="c" id="correct">  c. A donner une description de l'image si celle-ci ne peut pas s'afficher <br/>

        <h3>4. p{background-color : #000;} permet de définir : </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="a">  a. La couleur de la police du paragraphe <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="b" id="correct">  b. La couleur du fond du paragraphe <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="c">  c. Aucun des deux <br/>

        <h3>5. Laquelle de ces syntaxes est correcte pour écrire un commentaire en JavaScript ? </h3>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="a" id="correct">  a. // Commentaire <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="b">  b. / Commentaire / <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="c">  c. &lt;!-- Commentaire--&gt; <br/>

        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Valider" onclick="return validation()">
    </form>
</section>
```

I want to make right answers green and wrong answers into red, using JS CSS and HTML5 only, no framework needed. This is what I wrote in JS but didn't work :

```
document.forms.getElementById("correct").style.color = "green";
```

I don't understand why it didn't work. And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: IDs need to be unique

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, it stil didn't work do you have any idea on how to color correct answers ?

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3607291/4642212). Use classes instead. Use classes every time there is _an_ element of some kind, and IDs whenever there is _the_ element of some kind. You have five different correct answers, so each of them is _a_ correct answer, not _the_ correct answer.

Comment: "_I changed it, it stil didn't work_" isn't nearly enough information for us to be able to tell what you changed exactly.

Comment: Instead of using ID="correct" I used class="correct" for each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs need to be unique

Use a label and class - you cannot colour a radio

```js
//document.querySelectorAll(".correct").forEach(answer => answer.style.backgroundColor = "green")

document.querySelectorAll(".correct")[1].style.backgroundColor = "green"

// alternative

document.querySelector("[name=question3][value=c]").closest("label").style.backgroundColor = "green"
```

```html
<section>
  <form name="formulaire">
    <h3>1. Le rôle du HTML est de : </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="a"> a. Mettre en forme du texte</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="b"> b. Structurer un document</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="c"> c. Lier un document à une feuille de style</label><br/>

    <h3>2. Pour définir un titre dans une page HTML, on utilise : </h3>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="a"> a. La balise title</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="b"> b. La balise titre</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="c"> c. La balise head</label><br/>

    <h3>3. A quoi sert l'attribut alt de la balise img ? </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="a"> a. A afficher une deuxième image si la première ne peut pas s'afficher</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="b"> b. A donner un lien alternatif vers l'image si le premier est cassé</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="c"> c. A donner une description de l'image si celle-ci ne peut pas s'afficher</label><br/>

    <h3>4. Permet de définir : </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="a"> a. La couleur de la police du paragraphe</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="b"> b. La couleur du fond du paragraphe</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="c"> c. Aucun des deux</label><br/>

    <h3>5. Laquelle de ces syntaxes est correcte pour écrire un commentaire en JavaScript ? </h3>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="a"> a. // Commentaire</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question5" value="b"> b. / Commentaire /</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question5" value="c"> c. &lt;!-- Commentaire--&gt;</label><br/>

    </label><br/>
    <label><input type="submit" value="Valider" onclick="return validation()">
 </form>
</section>
```

Perhaps this

```js
document.getElementById("formulaire").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]").forEach(rad => {
    const label = rad.closest("label");
    const classList = label.classList;
    classList.remove("red","green")
    if (rad.checked) {
      classList.add(classList.contains("correct") ? "green" : "red");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.red { background-color: red;}
.green { background-color: green;}
```

```html
<section>
  <form id="formulaire">
    <h3>1. Le rôle du HTML est de : </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="a"> a. Mettre en forme du texte</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="b"> b. Structurer un document</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="c"> c. Lier un document à une feuille de style</label><br/>

    <h3>2. Pour définir un titre dans une page HTML, on utilise : </h3>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="a"> a. La balise title</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="b"> b. La balise titre</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question2" value="c"> c. La balise head</label><br/>

    <h3>3. A quoi sert l'attribut alt de la balise img ? </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="a"> a. A afficher une deuxième image si la première ne peut pas s'afficher</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question3" value="b"> b. A donner un lien alternatif vers l'image si le premier est cassé</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="c"> c. A donner une description de l'image si celle-ci ne peut pas s'afficher</label><br/>

    <h3>4. Permet de définir : </h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="a"> a. La couleur de la police du paragraphe</label><br/>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="b"> b. La couleur du fond du paragraphe</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question4" value="c"> c. Aucun des deux</label><br/>

    <h3>5. Laquelle de ces syntaxes est correcte pour écrire un commentaire en JavaScript ? </h3>
    <label class="correct"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="a"> a. // Commentaire</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question5" value="b"> b. / Commentaire /</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question5" value="c"> c. &lt;!-- Commentaire--&gt;</label><br/>

    </label><br/>
    <label><input type="submit" value="Valider">
 </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, can you please simplify this part `forEach(answer => answer.style.backgroundColor = "green")` so that I can apply it on one element ?

Comment: See update. The list starts at 0, so [0] is answer 1

Comment: You can also do `document.querySelector("[name=question3][value=c]").closest("label").style.backgroundColor = "green"`

Comment: Thank you so much your answer helped me a lot, here's what I did: `document.querySelector(".correct").style.backgroundColor = "green";` for every correct answer in HTML : `<input type="radio" name="question1" value="b"> <span class="correct"> b. Structurer un document </span> <br/>`

Comment: see my updated example to test if the background should be green red or white. I still suggest you use labels since the user can click on the sentence to check the radio. I changed form name to for ID

Answer (score 0):

The HTML id attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.

Use class instead.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

after that you can simply use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using class element instead of id, it still didn't work, do you have an ida on how to color an input ?

Comment: do you need to change the background colour or border colour? this link will cover most of the styles https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp and for checkbox, radio buttons use this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: I want to add a green color to inputs where class="correct" using JS, when the form is submitted. Actually, it's a quizz where the right answers should be colored in green and wrong answers in red. Using css it should be color:red; or color:green;

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="someClass"> 
  Hello World
</div>

<Script>
 var all = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
 for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  all[i].style.color = 'red';
 }
</script>
```

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work fine, as far as I can see.

The only problem that **I notice is that you have same ID in multiple place. Make ID unique,** it will work fine.

Hope that solves the problem.
ID must be unique.

Or use class for multiple ones!!

Comment: I changed it into class="correct" and still didn't work..