# JS change button value on click for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have got 3 buttons and need to change their text when it's clicked using Javascript. It works fine for the first one but the rest of them doesn't get updated. I know one way of achieving this is by adding JS for different inputs and id. But I just want to write a single function which solves this issue.

```
<input id=-btn" type="button" value="ADD" />

<input id="btn" type="button" value="ADD" />

<input id="btn" type="button" value="ADD" />


document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (event) {
          if (event.target.value === "ADD") {
            event.target.value = "ADDED";
          } else {
            event.target.value = "ADD";
          }
        },
        false
      );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript and getElementById for multiple elements with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id=-btn" type="button" value="ADD" onclick="func(this)"/>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="ADD"  onclick="func(this)"/>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="ADD" onclick="func(this)"/>


<script>
        function func(event) {
          if (event.value === "ADD") {
            event.value = "ADDED";
          } else {
            event.value = "ADD";
          }
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: thanks, would it be possible to do the same thing for <i> tags as well which changes the button color?

Comment: yes,just change the style color

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeValue(event) {
      if (event.target.value === "ADD") {
        event.target.value = "ADDED";
      } else {
        event.target.value = "ADD";
      }
    }
```

```html
    <input id="btn" onclick="changeValue(event)" type="button" value="ADD" />

    <input id="btn" onclick="changeValue(event)" type="button" value="ADD" />

    <input id="btn" onclick="changeValue(event)" type="button" value="ADD" />
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: please check new answer